# Tool for modifying large SQL insert statements

Tags: windows, sql

I am a software developer and I am working on a large project.

For our unit tests we have an SQL-file with lots of insert statements for our test database (In-Memory HSQL Database). Often I am facing the challenge that a few tables change, columns are removed or added and I have to apply those changes to our statements. I can't just copy the content of our real database, because the data have to stay the same. Also it's always a hassle because the syntax for the query is slightly different.

Right now I am working mostly with RegEx in Notepad++ and Excel to be able to insert new columns with data into the statements, but it's always a time consuming task. Depending on the table that I have to edit, sometimes there are several hundred statements for one table, and some table have several dozen columns.

Is there some kind of tool that would simplify this task?